# Populate Instance Variable Defined In Parent Controller For Rspec Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, applicationcontroller

In my ApplicationController, I expose a variable that can be shared by all controllers:

```
before_filter :expose_group

protected

    # Much simplified
    def expose_group
      @user_group = LearningGroup.find_by_uid(cookies[:user_group])
    end
```

I'm testing my controllers using RSpec, and for some of these tests, I need to be able to set the @user_group to a known value before they are run. How can I set this variable when testing a subclass of ApplicationController?

**Note: I need a way to set @user_group for the test. Controlling the return value of `expose_group` using a stub doesn't help as `@user_group` will still be nil.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would scrap the instance variable altogether and use helpers instead. Start with something like a `GroupsHelper` in `app/helpers/groups_helper.rb`.

```
module GroupsHelper
  def user_group
    @user_group ||= group_from_cookie
  end

  def user_group=(group)
    @user_group = group
  end

  private

  def group_from_cookie
    group_uid = cookies[:user_group]
    LearningGroup.find_by_uid group_uid unless group_uid.nil?
  end
end
```

Then `include` it in `ApplicationController`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include GroupsHelper
  # ...
end
```

Now, in `spec/support` define a helper for your test.

```
include ApplicationHelper

def join_group group_uid
  # whatever preparation you may need to do as well
  cookies[:user_group] = group_uid
end
```

A test could look something like:

```
it 'does something awesome' do
  join_group 'my awesome group id'
  # ...
  expect(your_subject).to be_awesome
end
```

When you run your test, `user_group` will return the value determined by the value you already assigned to the cookie object.

This also has the benefit of just calling `join_group` rather than stubbing `LearningGroup` all over the place in multiple tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply stub the method like:

```
LearningGroup.should_receive(:find_by_uid).and_return known_value
```

Comment: This would only allow me to control the return value of `expose_group`, but what I need is a way to populate the `@leaning_group` instance variable.

Comment: where is this variable defined?

Comment: It's defined right there in the `expose_group` method. It's defined there in the ApplicationController and used in the subclass that I'm testing.

Comment: you define `@user_group` there. the variable will be set with your known value if the before filter is executed. If it's not the `should_receive` will let you know

Comment: Sorry. I've got you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can stub `expose_group` method to return what you want.

In your specs:

```
controller.stub(expose_group: 'what you need')
```

Comment: But it's only returning anything implicitly. It's not the return value of `expose_group` that I need to control, but the instance variable.

Comment: In this case the answer of @apneadiving is what you need.